# what's different between ethereum and bitcoin p2p protocols?

Tags: p2p, ethereum, bitcoin

I wonder what's difference between ethereum and bitcoin p2p section.

I know that ethereum uses wire protocol. And it use receipts message, status message.

Is there any similar process in bitcoin?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for Google not really here as there are a huge amount of content written about the difference.

Since we're here, this is a video that explains in depth the differences between them:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0s23w5GUAeU